# Katalon Automation - Execute Scripts after Report Generation

Tags: java, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I would like to execute scripts after report generation, currently i am only able to make use of Listener class but this happens before Report creation.
Below sample for Listener Class.

```
@AfterTestSuite
    def sampleAfterTestSuite(TestSuiteContext testSuiteContext) {
        println testSuiteContext.getTestSuiteId()
        println ("Last Run...........");
        WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('EmailUtil'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)


}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work that way. I tried something [similar](https://forum.katalon.com/t/when-is-the-report-file-created).

My best guess would be to create two Test Suites and run them in a Test Suite Collection. The first TS will contain your current scripts, and the second one will call the `EmailUtil` test, after the TS1 finishes.

Comment: Thanks Mate. Basically i want to attached the pdf result to mail. Thus wondering if there is any way to execution email after report.

Comment: Try the two test suites solution.